# When a union negotiates a pay rise, do non-union workers also get that pay rise?

Tags: trade-unions

Do non-union members, in the same company and in the same roles, typically benefit from any negotiation successes of unionised employees' unions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about (regional) law, not the discipline of economics.

Comment: (To my knowledge the answer in some US states is "no".)

Comment: Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Sorry, it strikes my that I may have misunderstood your question: are you asking if the union negotiated pay raise also legally applies to non-union workers, or if the wages of non-union workers are also affected for non-legal reasons? (e.g., the company raises them voluntarily because it is afraid about these workers joining the union)

Comment: I'm asking whether negotiated improvements to pay and/or conditions are handed to non-union members who effectively played no part in the negotiation

Comment: Suppose the union negotiates a $1/hour raise for union employees, and the company, fearing further unionization raises the wage of non-union employees by 50 cents/hour. Do you consider this to be an instance where "negotiated improvements to pay and/or conditions are handed to non-union members"?